# Moving a div right animation not working

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying implement a small animation on a `div`. Whenever we click on the `div` it has to move right. I wrote some code but it is not working. Could anyone please help me?

here is my code

```
<style type="text/css">
    #animDiv
    {
        background-color:#6F0;
        width:87px;
        height:39px;
        left:10px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function $(id)
    {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    function moveRight()
    {   
        var elem     = $("animDiv");
        //var divPos = parseInt($("animDiv").style.left);
        var divPos   = $("animDiv").offsetLeft;
        var divWid   = $("animDiv").offsetWidth;

        if(divPos+divWid < 700) 
        {       
            $("animDiv").style.left = $("animDiv").style.left+100+"px";
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="animDiv" onclick="moveLeft()">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you use CSS3 transitions, or does it have to be a JS animation?

Comment: Does it need to be a smooth transition, or do you want it to jump to the right when you click? Can you use any JS libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- You are calling the wrong function. It is declared `moveRight()`
- You are attempting to change the `left` property which will have no affect on elements that are positioned statically.
- The element will only nudge right one time. After that the value for your `left` property is something like `100px100px`.

How is this:

```
function moveRight() {
    var elem = $("animDiv");
    //var divPos        =   parseInt($("animDiv").style.left);
    var divPos = $("animDiv").offsetLeft;
    var divWid = $("animDiv").offsetWidth;
    if (divPos + divWid < 700) {
        var curLeft = Number($("animDiv").style.left.replace("px", ""));
        $("animDiv").style.left = (curLeft + 100) + "px";
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D33rE/)

Answer (score 2):

try replacing this code

```
<div id="animDiv" onclick="moveLeft()">
```

with this code

```
<div id="animDiv" onclick="moveRight()">
```

and add style `position:fixed;` to your css.

Comment: thanks,it is working.do you know the reason for using "position:fixed".bcz after adding that only it worked

Comment: @ArsenIbragimov: more complete, it works with position: absolute/fixed/relative/sticky. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)